# Finding UV points Manually

Tags: c++, opengl

I followed this tutorial(http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-5-a-textured-cube/) on opengl to do a small school project.
And they used blender to find the uv coordiantes for their texture.
I don't understand blender very well.Is there any other way to find the coordinates easily?

My cuboid(14*8*1):https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BfZe.jpg 
Texture pack that i created https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oe7L9.jpg

My goal is to make something like this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRuc0.jpg

Comment: please share your attempts

Comment: Automatic texture coordinate generation still is an area of research. A lot of progress was made in the mid 2000-s and Blender, like every other contemporary modelling software implements the results of this research. But at the end of the day, defining the final texture coordinates for models is part of the artist's job, not of the programmer's. Of course for simple shapes you can specify the coordinates formally as well. But that's not how it works for the majority of geometry.